# Python imported class and list in a list

Tags: python, list

I've defined class (say for different car types) in file student.py:

```
class car:

    def __init__(self, name, engine, no_of_seats, power_source):
        self.name = name
        self.engine = engine
        self.no_of_seats = no_of_seats
        self.power_source = power_source
```

Then I've imported it to main_project.py

```
from student import car
```

I've created, say 3 different car types with data related to the class. Now I would like to print e.g. only power_source for all 3 car types with at once. My idea was to make list in a list but I doesn't work. Here is piece of my code:

```
list = [car("Audi", 2.0, 4, "gasoline")], [car("Porsche", 3.0, 7, "gasoline")], [car("Lexus", 2.4, 5, "hybrid")]
```

Now, I cannot access specific item in a list. I can access whole list but it prints following message:

I get this by using:

```
print(list[0])
```

My questions are:
- is the way I'm trying to achieve it proper?
- is it possible to include in the variable "list" other variables for different car types?

Thank you

Comment: ... Your `list` hides the built in - and is in fact a `tuple` of 1 element lists ...

Comment: Testing your code, I get `[<__main__.car instance at 0x7fd92dd41a50>]`. Please post a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

There are a few mistakes in your syntax that will cause problems. First, lit's considered bad practice to use "list" as a name for a list, as it overrides the builtin name list. Add an underscore at the end to be pythonic:

```
list_ = []
```

Next up, you use square brackets to close off every element of the list, when you should keep every element in the one pair of square brackets.

```
# Don't do this
list_ = [elem_1], [elem_2], [elem_3],...

# Do this
list_ = [elem_1, elem_2, elem_3]
```

And then finally, to answer your question, you are filling your list up with car objects. But you want to fill it up with the power_source attributes of the cars objects. So use dot syntax to call the attribute from the car object

```
list_ = [car("Audi", 2.0, 4, "gasoline").power_source, car("Porsche", 3.0, 7, "gasoline").power_source, car("Lexus", 2.4, 5, "hybrid").power_source]
```

Comment: you destroy the cars by only storign the power_source. Better do `cars = [car("Audi", 2.0, 4, "gasoline"), car("Porsche", 3.0, 7, "gasoline"), car("Lexus", 2.4, 5, "hybrid")]` and then `powersources = [a.power_source for a in car]`

Comment: "list is a protected name in python, so you are forbidden to use "list" as a name for a list" => plain wrong (if that was the case the code wouldn't compile). It's just a builtin name, you are free to override it, but this is indeed bad practice since it tends to confuse the reader and can create issues elsewhere.